# Processing GEE Raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, google-earth-engine

I am using the Google Earth plugin for QGIS.  I have the following code that returns the DEM for Oman.

```
    import ee;
    image = ee.Image("USGS/SRTMGL1_003");
    Oman = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL_SIMPLIFIED_500m/2015/level0");
    filter = ee.Filter.eq('ADM0_NAME','Oman');
    OmanFiltered = Oman.filter(filter);
    Map.addLayer(image.clip(OmanFiltered),{'palette': ['blue', 'red'], 'min': 0, 'max': 5000},'OmanDem',True);
```

The problem arises in that this resultant map has no extents being based on what is called a 'global composite' in GEE.  I cannot therefore `Export->Save As` the layer as a GeoTIFF with an error saying `'Attempt to create 0x0 dataset is illegal'`.  I guess that is because it has no extents.

I tried to draw a vector polygon in QGIS as a surround of the GEE supplied image above and then do a `Raster->Extraction->Clip Raster by Mask Layer` using the surrounding polygon but then got an error

```
 ERROR 4: `type=xyz&url=https://earthengine.googleapis.com/v1alpha/projects/earthengine-legacy/maps/c65a4d164f5547eb7fb9f7fe1c1b24df-c4621e8e2576f3167a45a4a52e46ec04/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name.
```

Does anyone have a solution to extracting the raster files from GEE in QGIS that allows them to be saved as a GeoTiff for further processing in QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

If you export your resulting `ee.Image` in your Google Drive [as shown in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/exporting), you will obtain a .tif file that you can then download and manipulate in QGIS.

in you case it could be something like :

```py
task_config = {
    'image':image,
    'description':'Oman_SRTMGL1_003',
    'scale': 30,
    'region': OmanFiltered.geometry()
}
                
task = ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive(**task_config)
task.start()
```

if you need to wait for the end of the process to start the next one listen to the `task` object:

```
while not(task.state == "SUCESS" or task.state == "FAILED"):
    time.sleep(10)
```

It will check every 10 seconds if the file is downloaded.

> There are no workaround the export step if you want .tif files

Comment: I did consider this, but there is a lag to the time that the file will arrive in google drive.  I wanted to access the data directly in code without having to wait for the file export.  Perhaps there is a way I can but a trigger on the file loading into the directory to kick off the next part of the processing